# Regular expression allowing zero-length string while editing

Tags: regex

So I'm trying to create a regular expression that will allow a user to change three numbers separated by colons. I'm currently using the following regex:

```
"\\b([1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|655[[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]|0)\\:([1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|655[[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]|0)\\:([1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|655[[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]|0)\\b"
```

It works for the most part and prevents any strings from being invalid, but there's an issue with editing the individual numbers.  Using `401:53:3` as an example, if I put my cursor to the far end of the entire string, I can hold backspace and delete the entire thing. Then I can type a valid value and save it (if it's invalid, it won't let me keep it).

The problem happens when I try to edit just one of the numbers. So, if I put my cursor in the `401` block at the end of the `1` and then hold backspace, it removes the last two numbers, but won't delete the `4`. This can be a hassle for a user that wants to change the first number, but doesn't want to rewrite the whole thing.

Does this make sense? Is there anyway that I can allow zero-length strings in my regular expression sections?

Comment: It does not seem true, since - if I get you right - the string is still matched with your regex, and thus is valid. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eF4zT0/1), feel free to modify to show what the actual issue looks like. Or do you want `:53:3` to also be matched with the regex?

Comment: Could you show us the rest of your code?

Comment: I am just guessing, but perhaps, [that is what you are looking for](https://regex101.com/r/yR1iM2/1).

Comment: @stribizhev So yeah, I suppose I would like to be able to match :53:3. The input is checked in two different circumstances. It is checked while it is being edited, and then again after it loses focus. If the input is wrong after the focus, it will revert to its original value. So, I think what you suggested in your second comment should work.  I'll try that out real quick.

Comment: I doubt you can use the same regex for both live validation (onkeyup) and final validation (onblur). You can use mine above for live validation and yours for final one. Makes sense? Or maybe sln's one below is working better? Please let me know if you think I should post this as an answer.

Comment: @stribizhev So that worked.  The regex you suggested did what I needed.  Thanks!  Now, how do I make it a suggested answer?

Comment: @Giblo: I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my suggestion since it proved working for you.

I suggest to allow matching the string even when a user is deleting the whole numeric subsection in the string. `\b` is matching at the word boundary, and thus does not let us match `\b:`, that is why I suggest adding an alternative with `\B` that matches at a non-word boundary.

We need to add it for all the numeric sections, so that they could become "optional".

```
(\b(?:[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|655[[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]|0)|\B):([1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|655[[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]|0|\B):((?:[1-9][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[1-5][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|6[0-4][0-9][0-9][0-9]|65[0-4][0-9][0-9]|655[[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]|0)\b|\B)
                                                                                                                             ^                                                                                                                         ^                                                                                                                               ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR1iM2/1)

Mind that this regex is only good for live validation. Final validation can be performed with your initial regex, I believe.